# How to have several overleftarrows of same height and length

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrows

I want to put arrows on top of various pieces of several  formulas but I want the arrows to be of the same size and height. What is a good solution? For example consider

```
\overleftarrow{x} \quad \overleftarrow{x^2} \quad \overrightarrow{3xy}
```

the arrows will naturally be at different heights and of different lengths  due to the varying sizes of the individual formula boxes. I want to force them to be more even.

Edit 1:

The promising suggestion was to use phantom to even out the height of arrows.

For now I decided to put the formulas into a tabular and allocate a row for the arrows and adjust the spacing between the rows.

Edit 2:
Here is a MWE without phantom or separate rows for the arrows, etc.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \def \ra {\overrightarrow}
 \def \la {\overleftarrow}
 \begin{document}    
 \begin{tabular}{cccc}
  $\ra A$& $\la{ E^2}$ &$\la {5FG^3}$& $\ra{ H^2 I^3}$\\ 
  $\ra {BA^5} $& $\ra {AE^2}$ &$\ra {G}$& $\ra {12 H^2 I^3}$\\ 
 \end{tabular}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a MWE

Comment: Use a `\vphantom` of the tallest element; that is `\vphantom{x^2}` in this case, and insert it in the other not-as-tall elements: `\overleftarrow{\vphantom{x^2}x}`

Comment: On the other hand, an arrow hanging from nowhere doesn't seem the best.

Comment: So you have several pieces of a formula on which to put an arrow. For the "the same heigh" part, if you want them _at_ the same height, @Werner's comment will help. If you want them _of_ the same height, well, I don't get that. With "of" it sounds more like the arrows for some reason are of different thicknesses. This is more of a vocabulary note, but mind your preposotions :), because I guess they don't turn out to have different thicknesses. As for the size and length, well, for the size again I don't get the problem, for the lengths you can try fiddling with `\hspace`s or `\phantom`s.

Comment: Or maybe you can superimpose an arrow with a `\phantom` of the longest element with the others, either by a negative `\hspace` or by a `\mathaccent`, but I fail to see why you would want that. In general, I suggest you post your actual problem, the desired result and maybe your own attempt.

Comment: And I fully agree with @egreg :): indeed, seeing examples of usage of `\vphantom` for that purpose has made me wonder why on earth someone would want that :).

Comment: So has the `\vphantom` solved your problem?

Comment: @Werner it solves the height problem, but I still need to adjust the width/length so that arrows have the same length. I suppose I should use a \hphantom too. But when I do it does not center correctly.

Comment: @Maesumi: Yes, one would probably use `\mathclap{<stuff>}\hphantom{<long entry>}` (using [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the arrows to be at the same vertical height it you apply a `\vphantom{<text>}` with `<text>` being the tallest content, and if you want them to be the same width you can typeset the content into a fixed width `\makebox`.  In this case `x^2` is the tallest content, so we get:

[image]

---

In the above, I fixed the width of the `\makebox` to be `2.0em`. If you have much wider content you can either adjust this width manually, or set it to be equal to the widest content that you have.  So, in the second example I assumes that `ABCD` is your widest element so now the width of the arrow is just enough to cover `ABCD`:

[image]

This can also be done using `\mathmakebox`.

---

### Code: Fixed Width:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{mathtools}

 \newcommand*{\TallestContent}{$x^2$}% <-- This should be the tallest content

 \newcommand*{\ra}[1]{\overrightarrow{\makebox[2.0em]{$#1$\vphantom{\TallestContent}}}}
 \newcommand*{\la}[1]{\overleftarrow{\makebox[2.0em]{$#1$\vphantom{\TallestContent}}}}

 \begin{document}    
     $\la{x} \quad \la{x^2} \quad \ra{3xy}$
 \end{document}
```

---

### Code: Measured Width using `\makebox`:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{mathtools}

  \newcommand*{\WidestContent}{$ABCD$}% <-- This should be the widest content
  \newcommand*{\TallestContent}{$x^2$}% <-- This should be the tallest content

  \newlength{\MyWidth}
  \settowidth{\MyWidth}{\WidestContent}% 

 \newcommand*{\ra}[1]{\overrightarrow{\makebox[\MyWidth]{$#1$\vphantom{\TallestContent}}}}
 \newcommand*{\la}[1]{\overleftarrow{\makebox[\MyWidth]{$#1$\vphantom{\TallestContent}}}}

 \begin{document}    
     $\la{x} \quad \la{x^2} \quad \ra{3xy} \quad \ra{ABCD}$
 \end{document}
```

### Code: Measured Width using `\mathmakebox`:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{mathtools}

  \newcommand*{\WidestContent}{ABCD}% <-- This should be the widest content
  \newcommand*{\TallestContent}{x^2}% <-- This should be the tallest content

  \newlength{\MyWidth}
  \settowidth{\MyWidth}{\WidestContent}% 

  \newcommand*{\ra}[1]{\overrightarrow{\mathmakebox[\MyWidth]{#1\vphantom{\TallestContent}}}}
  \newcommand*{\la}[1]{\overleftarrow{\mathmakebox[\MyWidth]{#1\vphantom{\TallestContent}}}}

 \begin{document}    
     $\la{x} \quad \la{x^2} \quad \ra{3xy} \quad \ra{ABCD}$
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Or `\mathmakebox`. However the heights are not the same in the picture.

Comment: @egreg: Oh, I did not know about `\mathmakebox` -- Will have to look into that. Thanks for point out the slight difference in the height -- guess I have to resort to a `\vphantom{}`.